# How to check existed udf's and triggers in cassandra?

Tags: triggers, cassandra, user-defined-functions, udf, cqlsh

I created two udf's and one trigger in Cassandra cqlsh.How to check existed udf's and triggers in cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list existing functions with:

```
DESCRIBE FUNCTIONS;
```

and you can get the triggers from the schema table:

```
SELECT * from system_schema.triggers;
```

Comment: Thanks mikea.. would you please help me in how can I call them in java code by using datastax java driver..